# Powerpoint Keyboard Shortcut to “Save as Picture…” for selected item

Tags: keyboard, ms-office, shortcut

I use ppt all the time to make quick images for export as png, jpg, etc... To export, I right-click on the object and choose "Save as Picture..." This avoids the layers of menus File-->Export-->etc...

My question is, how can I make a keyboard shortcut that will do the same thing as right clicking on an object and choosing "Save as Picture..."? (A)
[image]
If it is not possible, can I make a macro and assign a keyboard shortcut to that? If so, any pointers?

Here's what I've tried so far: Using System Setting --> keyboard --> with several different key combinations (to avoid conflicts), but that didn't work (B) and I could not find "Save as Picture..." among the Ribbon/Quick Access Toolbar customization commands (C).

Comment: The answer might be "because Microsoft" but I'd check a couple of things - first, are you certain you used an ellipsis `…` not 3 full-stops `...` & 2nd, see if one of the simpler commands above will work with a new key command; copy/paste or Edit etc

Comment: @Tetsujin I appreciate the cleverness of your idea, so I spent some time testing. First, I tested with the regular menu item Format-->Font... and found that I was able to change it to the shortcut I had been trying (option-cmd-P) regardless of whether it was 3 dots or an ellipsis (one character). Then I tried to mimic other right-click menu items (Add Sketch and Edit Points) but was unable to make either work. That suggests that the problem is making shortcuts for right-click menu items. I appreciate this insight, but I'm still stuck.

Comment: Ahh, sorry - I hadn't realised the option was **only** available in a right-click menu. I'm really not sure how to approach that. You can *force* navigation of a regular menu - usually done if an item appears more than once in different menus & you want one specific instance, by using eg `Menu->Sub Menu->Item` formatting in your shortcut